# how to display the clicked radio button value on my second activity in android studio?

Tags: java, android

This is my java code:

```
public class jenis extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button button3;
    RadioGroup radioGroup2;
    RadioButton radioButton2;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_jenis);

        radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        final RadioButton stock = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton11);
        final RadioButton property = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton12);

        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (stock.isChecked()){
                    Variable newVar = new Variable();
                    newVar.setAmountt("jeniss");
                    databaseReference.child(newVar.getAmountt()).setValue("Stock Waqf");
                }

                else if(property.isChecked()){
                    Variable newVar = new Variable();
                    newVar.setAmountt("jeniss");
                    databaseReference.child(newVar.getAmountt()).setValue("Property Waqf");
                }

                if(stock.isChecked()){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(jenis.this, stock.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                if(property.isChecked()){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(jenis.this, property.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

How can I display the clicked radio button value on my second activity?

I really appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Pass the value one activity to another using Intent..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: What do you mean by *clicked radio button value*? Do you mean `true` because it is checked or do you mean the text label of the `RadioButton`?

Comment: If you mean passing clicked button's value to another activity, use `intent`, or just store in a variable and access the variable in another activity.

Answer (score 1):

pass the value as intent

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(youractivity.this,secondactivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("key",radiobutton.getText());
 startActivity(intent);
```

to access it on second activity

```
in OnCreate() method
    getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

or else

```
 you can also store your radiobutton checked value in shared preference and 
  then access it on another activity... It will work like session
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class stock extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseReference databaseReference;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stock);

    final TextView textViewOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewOut2);


    textViewOut.setText(" ");


}

public void OnCreate() {
    getIntent().getStringExtra("jeniss");
   }

}
```

what did i missed ?